# integral and function

Tags: calculus

I have:
$$ A=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sqrt {\frac {1} {(t^2-1)^2}- \frac {(n+1)^2t^{2n}} {(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}\,dt$$

But how to prove

$$A=4 \int_0^1 \sqrt {\frac {1} {(t^2-1)^2}- \frac {(n+1)^2t^{2n}} {(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}\,dt?$$

For the moment I have:
$$A=2\int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt {\frac {1} {(t^2-1)^2}- \frac {(n+1)^2t^{2n}} {(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$
but after?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\int_1^{+\infty} \sqrt {\frac {1} {(t^2-1)^2}- \frac {(n+1)^2t^{2n}} {(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$

and apply the chance ov variable $x=1/t$. You get

$$\int_0^{1} \sqrt {\frac {1} {(x^2-1)^2}- \frac {(n+1)^2x^{2n}} {(x^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$